# не могу объединить в одну таблицу sql managment studio

Tags: sql, select

есть скрипт

```
        SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bill_id ASC) AS rownumber,
   b.bill_id as bill_id1  FROM Bills b
    WHERE b.pay_id = 6179 and b.advtype = 1 
        and b.rperiod_beg =convert(datetime, '2020-12-01 00:00:00.000',102)
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber = 1

        SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bill_id ASC) AS rownumber,
   b.bill_id as bill_id2  FROM Bills b
    WHERE b.pay_id = 6179 and b.advtype = 1 
        and b.rperiod_beg =convert(datetime, '2020-12-01 00:00:00.000',102)
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber = 2

        SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bill_id ASC) AS rownumber,
   b.bill_id as bill_id3  FROM Bills b
    WHERE b.pay_id = 6179 and b.advtype = 1 
        and b.rperiod_beg =convert(datetime, '2020-12-01 00:00:00.000',102)
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber = 3
```

он выдает такой результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы результат выводился так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы я мог потом во временную таблицу записать

Comment: зачем вам 3 запроса различающиеся лишь `rownumber = 1,2,3` а не один с `rownumber <= 3` ?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы данные попадали в колонки bill_id1,bill_id2 и bill_id3. в зависимости от условий может выводиться либо 3 значения либо 2 либо 1. по этому указав <=3 значения попадают только в колонку bill_id1

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если сделать именно то, что Вы просите, и используя Ваш запрос, то вот -

```
SELECT  b1.bill_id1, b2.bill_id2, b3.bill_id3
FROM (SELECT bill_id1 FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bill_id ASC) AS rownumber,
   b.bill_id as bill_id1  FROM Bills b
    WHERE b.pay_id = 6179 and b.advtype = 1 
        and b.rperiod_beg =convert(datetime, '2020-12-01 00:00:00.000',102)
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber = 1) b1 left join
(        SELECT bill_id2 FROM (
  SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bill_id ASC) AS rownumber,
   b.bill_id as bill_id2  FROM Bills b
    WHERE b.pay_id = 6179 and b.advtype = 1 
        and b.rperiod_beg =convert(datetime, '2020-12-01 00:00:00.000',102)
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber = 2) b2 ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bill_id ASC) AS rownumber,
   b.bill_id as bill_id3  FROM Bills b
    WHERE b.pay_id = 6179 and b.advtype = 1 
        and b.rperiod_beg =convert(datetime, '2020-12-01 00:00:00.000',102)
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber = 3) b3 ON 1=1
```

но это выглядит странно, даж немного страшно :)